# What's wrong with my CSR inf generation? Giving a Keyspec error

Tags: c#, .net, windows-server-2008, x509certificate2

I'm writing a C# program that will create inf files and then run a certreq -new to generate the CSR and output the contents - On older machines ( Windows server 2008, for instance ) I'm getting a generic error

`"[NewRequest] KeyAlgorithm = "ECDSA_P256" <=> KeySpec?`

Editing the CSR file manually and removing the KeySpec altogether seems to make the CSR go through, but every guide I see seems to mention the KeySpec, so I'm confused whether I'm doing something wrong or what.

```cs
string[] csrPairs = {"[NewRequest]", subjectLine, "Exportable = true", "ExportableEncrypted = true", "HashAlgorithm = sha256",
      "KeyAlgorithm = " + keyAlgorithm, "KeyLength = " + keysize, "KeySpec = 1", "MachineKeySet = true", "ProviderName = \"Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider\"","RequestType = PKCS10", "SMIME = false", "UseExistingKeySet = false"};
```

Here's the code I'm using to generate the CSR, seems to work on Windows 10, but not Windows 2008 Server.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - Is there something about Windows Serer 2008 I'm not thinking of? Or something my new computer would have set for .net that the other doesn't? (Target version 3.5)

Side note - Any help understanding keyspec would be great, too. Seems "1" means it can sign and encrypt, "2" can only sign - Not sure the default or what 0 does, or if I'm supposed to do anything else here.

Comment: Try replacing `= 1` with `= AT_KEYEXCHANGE`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Same error, though.

Getting rid of either the KeyAlgorithm or KeySpec fields makes it work just fine - I'm worried about the implications of both, though. Am I trusting the system to decide what I'm getting back if I remove KeyAlgorithm, and is the key going to be usable in the way people want if I remove KeySpec...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm think I figured some things out.

CNG ( Cryptography API: Next Generation ) providers don't use KeySpec, it's just set to 0 - it seems this setting might mess with some things though, such as creating Code Signing CSR's.

Regular CSP/Legacy providers seem to be able to determine the key you want in some cases, so setting the KeySpec but no the key algorithm works fine - at least from my testing.